# What is the process of adding a domain name to the DNS system?

Tags: dns, domain-name

For example, if I wanted to add "www.mycompany.com" to the DNS system, what happens (network-wise) when this process is being done?

Comment: What do you mean by add to the DNS system ? Do you own a DNS server ? What are you working on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one) `mycompany.com` is bought and registered. your details are added to a huge database.
Step two) Using tools provided by the company you register the domain from, the common thing to do by anyone who is relatively savvy with this stuff is to create GLUE records. These are subdomains eg. `ns1.mycompany.com`. You point each of these glue records to an IP address. This is stored in the huge DNS servers run by the country where the TLD (`.com`) is owned. These DNS servers usually have a domain name such as ns1.nic.com.
Step three) the subdomain glue record that was created in step two points to the DNS servers for the "zone" (the technical term for domain). These DNS servers answer requests for "`*.mycompany.com`", just how the root servers (from step two) answer for "`*.com`".
Step four) When you add a record to your DNS server, for example, an A record for "sub.mycompany.com", your DNS server will tell anyone who requests sub.mycompany.com what the IP address is.

Comment: Upvoting.  This doesn't actually answer the question, but should.  The "www." portion of "www.mycompany.com" is called a subdomain, so what MyNameWouldGoHere says about "sub.mycompany.com" applies as instructions to handle the "www.mycompany.com" example.  It is also common to add an "A" resource record to the DNS server for the base name (mycompany.com) that goes to the same spot as the www.mycompany.com.  Smreks: For future questions, it is more standardized to use names from [RFC 2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) (like "example.com"/"www.example.com")

Comment: I was at work when I wrote this so had to keep it short, but thanks for the extra parts, toogam :)